# Read only drop down

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xhtml

Is there a good way to make an HTML dropdown read only. Using disabled attribute of select seems to work, but the value is not posted.

```
<select disabled="disabled">
```

I have a complex page with lots of javascript and ajax. Some actions in the form cause to drop down to be read only some actions let user decide the value.

Edit: Is there a better way other than using a hidden input?

Comment: The value is not posted?  Do you mean it's not posted back to the server when the containing form is submitted?  If so, you're right it won't be submitted, but why would need it to be submitted?  If necessary, use JavaScript to set the value of a hidden field in addition to disabling the dop-down - that value will be posted back.

Comment: Yes, I meant it's not posted to the server when the containing form is submitted. I can use the hidden field idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want user to pick an option, how is this different from read-only input type="text"?

Comment: Or present an unordered list on the page of the options that could be available.

Comment: A select drop-down option has two properties, the value and the text. The value is often not legible, and the text is not a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="selectbox" disabled="disabled">
<option>option 1</option>
<option selected="selected">option 2</option>
<option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but if an option is selected, the value is sent